# What are the values of the detection events created by magic effects and weapons in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The formula behind detection events in Skyrim is described in the [Creation Kit](https://www.creationkit.com/index.php?title=Category:Detection).  Magic effects and weapons have fields in the their Creation Kit entries that correspond to how loud they are with four possible values: Silent, Normal, Loud, and Very Loud.  (The underlying integers corresponding to those fields in the data files are 2 = Silent, 1 = Normal, 0 = Loud, and 3 = Very Loud, so those values clearly aren't used for the detection event, otherwise Loud effects and weapons would make no noise while Silent effects and weapons would make noise.)  What are the actual detection values corresponding to Silent, Normal, Loud, and Very Loud events?

Comment: You're being distracted by the coincidence regarding the numerical values.  You need to actually determine whether it actually is the way you think it is before concluding that "those values clearly aren't used for the detection event".

Comment: It *is* clear that those values aren't the values of the sounds being made, which I think is what they're trying to say. 0 = loud and 3 = very loud with Silent and Normal in between makes it very clear that those values are not the actual loudness values, as they aren't in order. They look like they're just enum indices.